# If a curve doesn't pass vertical line test, it's a not a function then is $x= |\sin y|$ a function?

Tags: functions

My teacher told me if a vertical line intersects a curve more than once then the curve is NOT the graph of a function.

But what if I express $ x$ in terms of $y$?  As in $x= f(y) $

Eg : $ x = \left| \sin y \right|$
[image: Graph]

Clearly a vertical line $x = \dfrac{1}{2}$ intersects this curve more than once!

So is $x= | \sin y | $ not a function?

Comment: $x$ is a function of $y$, but $y$ is not a function of $x$

Comment: Check the well-definedness from the side of $y$

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is a function of $y$ but $y$ is not a function of $x$.

$y$ is not a function of $x$ has been explained by you.

For each value of $y$, we have a unique corresponding value, hence $x$ is a function of $y$ where the domain is $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: It is a function right? And it still fails vertical line test? How? Why?

Comment: Depending on your reference of "it". $y$ is not a function of $x$. function is something that when you give it a a valid input, it return an output. now if you give $x=0.5$, there are so many values of $y$.